# Compilation works in Eclipse but not in maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

The following piece of code using apache poi library results in compilation error when using maven with jdk 7. It works when using jdk 8.

```
    cell.getCellTypeEnum()

    [ERROR]   symbol:   method getCellTypeEnum()
    [ERROR]   location: variable cell of type org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell
```

The poi library used is 3.17 for both scenarios

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
       <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

The maven dependency tree is as follows.

```
[INFO] com.iris.gst:txform:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.04:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
```

It also works perfectly in Eclipse. The eclipse project has been created using mvn eclipse:eclipse. Why does it not work with jdk 7 ?

Comment: has it occurs that then the problem is not maven, but probably the jdk you are using? Check the (complete) error message

Comment: build your project again.

Comment: tried cleaning and rebuilding. same error.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: why does it not work with jdk 7 ?

Comment: @SourajitBasak Which 'same error'? show the complete stacktrace

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project txform: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /E:/src/sapphire/txform/src/main/java/com/iris/gst/readers/ExcelReader.java:[45,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getCellTypeEnum()
[ERROR]   location: variable cell of type org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell

Comment: Are you sure you have added the correct version of the dependency in Maven. Eclipse does not use Maven dependencies by default, but project based dependencies. These might be out of sync (version wise)

Comment: the eclipse project was created using mvn eclipse:eclipse. both have the same dependency

Comment: The `Cell` class having `method getCellTypeEnum()` is in 
`<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId><artifactId>poi</artifactId><version>3.17</version>` which is `poi-3.17.jar`. The error states, that somewhere in the compile time class path of your `Java 7` environment is a `poi-*.jar` from a version having `\org\apache\poi\ss\usermodel\Cell.class` which not has that method.

Comment: Have explicitly included it as well.                                                 
  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
       <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
       <version>3.17</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>                                                                                                    Still the same error.

Comment: The need is determining the `poi-*.jar` from a version **other** than `3.17` which must be in compile time class path to lead to that error.

Comment: verified the presence of the correct jars using mvn dependency:build-classpath. The jars are correctly listed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved.
In JDK 7 jre/lib/ext there is a poi-3.6.jar present. That was causing the problem.